# How to get line breaks in message supplied for Android Sharing

Tags: android, gmail, sharing, line-breaks

Android Sharing Intent takes a string for the body.

How do you introduce a line break? Gmail appears to do plain text by default, and so I can't get any line breaks in my sharing message.

\n, 
, <br />, and 0x0A all don't work.

Comment: I remember using `\n` in the past. Does it work for other share options like SMS?

Answer (score 0):

Okay \n does indeed work. And if you change the sharing intent setType to text\html, then < br />.

My problem was caused by issues inside HTML templating and then sent through a phonegap sharing plugin.